# Django. Sending email with an application

Tags: python, django, django-views

I started a new application gmail and configured settings in settings.py with my gmail account

I'm new in django and I don't know how to send emails to my website users

I would like to create a link that when I open it my user will get a message from me

I have edited views.py but I don't know what my function "wyslij" should return

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from userprofile.models import UserProfile


@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
# Create your views here.
def wyslij(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.


    uzyt = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('user_id')



    for z, uzyt in enumerate(UserProfile.objects.all()):

        send_mail('The exam is comming', 'Hi, Your exam will be tomorrow!', 'santa.claus.for.grace@gmail.com', [uzyt.email], fail_silently=False)


    return response
```

In urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/wyslij/$', 'gmail.views.wyslij'),
)
```

Comment: and what is the result? error messages? do you have all the correct EMAIL_* variables in settings.py set?

Comment: Is that HttpResponse ? what is the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings.py, you have to add these liner:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 587    #or try with 25
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/

be sure to name your EMAIL variables and .gitignore your settings file